# How to Scrape a website without disabling ssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, web-scraping, nokogiri

I have to scrape a website without disabling SSL. I tried by using Nokogiri gem

```
require 'httparty'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'


page = open("https://mywebsiteurl.com",{ssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE})
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(page)
puts doc
```

This code works by disabling SSL. but I want it to work without disabling SSL.

when I tried without disabling SSL I got this error

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

when I do `curl https://mywebsiteurl.com` I got this result.

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* Connected to wxxxxxxxxx.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Comment: Looks to me it still tries to verify the certificate. Either add proper certs in your keystore or find a better way to ignore it

Comment: Why exactly it failed to verify the certificate is not clear. Might be because the certificate is self-signed, does not match the URL, is expired, server is misconfigured and misses intermediate certificates, signed by an untrusted CA ... . Because of this it is also not possible to clearly point out how to fix it. If you would provide the real URL one might check what's wrong, provided the URL is publicly accessible.

Comment: actually it works if i tries in local but in production server this issue arises.

Comment: url is this one "https://womgroup.com/robots.txt"

Comment: it's probably failing on production server b/c the server does not have a root public number to verify the cert presented by the site you're scraping. Suggest you log into the server and do `curl -v https://mywebsiteurl.com` and see if you can get some more explanation.

Comment: @Les Nightingill When i do this it shows ssl certification from the sever that i/m trying to connect is expired .updated the result above. Is that be the issue.?. in local no such issues arises why?

Comment: you need to determine if the server cert has actually expired. Visit the site with your browser and use dev tools (e.g. chrome) to examine the validity of the cert.

Comment: it shows expired.